# html5-jquery change of checkbox not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the method described in https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/ to implement an on/off switch in html5.

The switch itself works fine, click on it and it gets the other state and you can query the checked state of the input/checkbox and that too works as expected.

When you click the switch I'd like some action to be performed from javaScript, but there is no event I can capture that does the job.

Any suggestions ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myonoffswitch').change(function () {
              dosomething();
        });
    
    });
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
        margin-top: 15px;
        position: relative;
        width: 90px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-label {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-inner {
        display: block;
        width: 200%;
        margin-left: -100%;
        transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    
        .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 30px;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: white;
            font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        .onoffswitch-inner:before {
            content: "User";
            padding-left: 10px;
            background-color: #70FF99;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
    
        .onoffswitch-inner:after {
            content: "Admin";
            padding-right: 10px;
            background-color: #EB5555;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: right;
        }
    
    .onoffswitch-switch {
        display: block;
        width: 18px;
        margin: 6px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 56px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 20px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
        right: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: All looks good. Have you tried adding console.log('test') in the handler to ensure it is firing? Perhaps something is off with the dosomething(); function.

Comment: The code you provided should do exactly what you're looking for. What's not working about it?

Comment: It is for a weird reason never triggered. I have some extra code in front of $('#myonoffswitch').change... that code get's called so I'm sure the script file is actually loaded and called. In dev tools there are no errors.

Comment: It's triggering fine for me using the exact code you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it is working fine for me..

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myonoffswitch').change(function () {
              console.log('Hello');
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If I embed the script it works fine. So it has to do with the moment of loading the script. Apparently it gets loaded before the slider is rendered, hence it cannot attach the event.

Comment: yes. It lead me to the reason why it was not working as expected and give the fact this part of the page was loaded dynamically. Embedding this small script is a good solution.

Comment: Good to hear this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is working fine. All you have to do is execute your operation inside the change action of the switch.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myonoffswitch').change(function () {
              console.log('works');
        });
    
    });
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
        margin-top: 15px;
        position: relative;
        width: 90px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-checkbox {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-label {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-inner {
        display: block;
        width: 200%;
        margin-left: -100%;
        transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    
        .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            height: 30px;
            padding: 0;
            line-height: 30px;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: white;
            font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    
        .onoffswitch-inner:before {
            content: "User";
            padding-left: 10px;
            background-color: #70FF99;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
    
        .onoffswitch-inner:after {
            content: "Admin";
            padding-right: 10px;
            background-color: #EB5555;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: right;
        }
    
    .onoffswitch-switch {
        display: block;
        width: 18px;
        margin: 6px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 56px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 20px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    
    .onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
        right: 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
```